# React placement of helper functions best practices

Tags: reactjs

I've been struggling with placement of helper functions in React for a while now (e.g. declare helpers inside the component or outside). I've been searching for best practices every where and was not able to have something that's super convincing. I've experimented with both and I'm having a hard time deciding which way is more beneficial. I'm wondering if people have different thoughts on this issue.

Benefits Helper functions declared inside a component:

- has access to props and hooks

Con:

- makes your component a bit clutter,
- invocations without any params that result in a bunch of side effects is not particularly attractive
- not easily exposed for tests

Benefits of helper functions outside of component:

- easily exposed for tests
- perhaps more declarative?

Cons:

- loses context of the helper functions because they're often created for a specific component
- requires you to go back and forth between files
- not DRY because props and hooks need to be passed in as arguments again

Comment: I'd say better to put helper functions outside. React is only a UI library so be careful with putting more than you need in a component. Architecturally it does not really make any sense to make your React component anything other than plain dumb and deal with the least logic possible. You can get around the loss of context by passing parameters to the helper function or else if you really need the same context you can use the Javascript native method 'call', which allows you to pass a context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO, put helpers outside. Your cons are not cons

- If a helper is specific to a component, then it is not a helper.
- The DRY principle refers to repeating logic rather than data

Comment: What about functions specific to to a component? Do you declare them inside or outside of the component?

Comment: Give me an example

Comment: Let's say you have Login component, and you have a button that does auth. Your auth logic does 10 different things (e.g. calls your custom auth module, connects database for user profile, dispatches redux, and then updates database with new attributes). Where do you put that logic? Inside or outside of the component? If it's a class, do you declare an `auth` method inside the class with no params and just invoke it?

Comment: The logic of fetching and updating the user profile is an async action or a sagas concern, put it in your actions folder. If you need to login from different parts of your app, just navigate to LoginScreen. LoginScreen has a button that dispatch the auth action using the username and password as payload. Auth action call auth api using the action's payload (username and password), if you have a class with an auth method to call auth api, then use it (from auth action) and pass in the username and password as parameter

Comment: I know they are actions, but you need to dispatch the action after the initial auth. So if the logic for clicking the button is, authAPI -> fetchUserProfile (api + dispatch redux) -> fetchBunchOfOtherStuff -> doSomeLogic -> dispatch another action based on previous logic. Where do you put the function that chains them together? Inside the component or outside?

Comment: This flow _" authAPI -> fetchUserProfile (api + dispatch redux) -> fetchBunchOfOtherStuff -> doSomeLogic -> dispatch another action based on previous logic"_  you are describing fits the flow of a saga/asynchronous action, therefore it should be outside the component

Answer (score 1):

If your helper function belongs only to one component and are not used outside even not use external resourses, only some kind of specially render logic, you can treat as component logic.

If your helper function belongs to multiples components or projects, you will be breaking DRY rules repeting code and maybe adding logic that dont belong to component itself. So makes sense to create a helper function outsite component and treat the values that come from context and hooks as arguments of external function library, that can be reused over several projects.